# Insert into Vertica if table does not exist or not a duplicate row

Tags: python, pandas, insert, vertica

I have written a python script to create a table using a `create table if not exists` statement and then insert rows from dataframe into vertica database. For the first time when I run this python script, I want it to create a table and insert the data - it works fine.

But from next time onwards, I want it to create a table only if it does not exist (works fine) and insert data only if that row is not contained in the database.

I use both `insert` statement and `COPY` statement to insert data. How to do this in python ? I am accessing Vertica database from python using pyodbc.

**Editing the post to include some code :**
There is a dataframe called tableframe_df , from which I need to populate content into a table created as bellow:

I am creating a table in vertica with create table if not exists, which creates a table if there is not one.

```
  cursor.execute("create table if not exists <tablename>  (fields in the table)")

COPY statement to write to this table from a csv that was created 
`cursor.execute("COPY tablename1 FROM LOCAL 'tablename.csv' DELIMITER ',' exceptions 'exceptions' rejected data 'rejected'")`

##for i,row in tablename_df.iterrows():
       cursor.execute("insert into tablename2 values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)",row.values[0],row.values[1],row.values[2],row.values[3],row.values[4],row.values[5],row.values[6],row.values[7],row.values[8],row.values[9],row.values[10],row.values[11])
```

Here in the above code, I am creating table and then inserting into tablename1 and tablename2 using COPY and insert. This works fine when executed the first time ( as there is no data in the table). Now by mistake if I run the same script twice, the data will be inserted twice in these tables. **What check should I perform to ensure that data does not get inserted if it is already present?**

Comment: You need to actually show the Python code you need help with. We don't write the code for you.

Comment: It isn't clear what you are asking. Specifically what are you trying to figure out how to do in Python?  `COPY`?  Or the `INSERT` only when data for that row does not exist in the target? Or both?

Comment: I am looking for both, COPY or Insert only when data for that row does not exist in the target. As @kermit asked, I will include the code I am looking for

Comment: *"What check should I perform to ensure that data does not get inserted if it is already present?"* Load into a staging table and use `NOT EXISTS` or a `MERGE`

Comment: @Kermit : can you give an example with code?

Comment: Sure. My rate is $130/hr.

Answer (score 1):

First I'll mention that `INSERT VALUES` is pretty slow if you are doing a lot of rows.  If you are using batch sql and the standard vertica drivers, it should convert it to a `COPY` but if it doesn't then your inserts might take forever. I don't think this will happen with `pyodbc` since they don't implement `executemany()` optimally.  You might be able to with `ceodbc` though, but I haven't tried it.  Alternatively, you can use `vertica_python` which has a `.copy('COPY FROM STDIN...',data)` command that is efficient.

Anyhow, for your question...

You can do it one of two ways.  Also for the inserts, I would really try to change this to a copy or at least an `executemany`.  Again, `pydobc` does not do this properly, at least for the releases that I have used.

1. Use a control table that somehow uniquely describe the set of data being loaded and insert into it and check before running the script that the data set has not been loaded.

   --Step 1. Check control table for data set load.

   ```
   SELECT *
   FROM   mycontroltable
   WHERE  dataset = ?
   ```

   --Step 2. If row not found, insert rows

   ```
   for row in data:
       cursor.execute('INSERT INTO mytargettable....VALUES(...)')
   ```

   -- Step 3. Insert row into control table

   ```
   INSERT INTO mycontroltable( dataset ) VALUES ( ? )
   ```

   -- Step 4. Commit data

   ```
   COMMIT
   ```
2. Alternatively you can insert or merge data in based on a key.  You can create a temp or other staging table to do it. If you don't want updates and data does not change once inserted, then INSERT will be better as it will not incur a delete vector.  I'll do `INSERT` based on the way you phrased your question.

   --Step 1. Create local temp for intermediate target

   ```
   CREATE LOCAL TEMP TABLE mytemp (fields) ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS;
   ```

   --Step 2. Insert data.

   ```
   for row in data: 
       cursor.execute('INSERT INTO mytemp....VALUES(...)')
   ```

   --Step 3. Insert/select only data that doesn't exist by key value

   ```
   INSERT INTO mytargettable (fields)
   SELECT fields
   FROM mytemp 
   WHERE NOT EXISTS (
       SELECT 1  
       FROM   mytargettable t
       WHERE  t.key = mytemp.key
   )
   ```

   --Step 4. Commit

   ```
   COMMIT;
   ```